# Not knowing exactly what to do while sending data from android app to laravel webpage using retrofit2

Tags: java, android, laravel, retrofit2

I have a laravel web page and an android app. I’m using retrofit2 to make both sites communicate. I know how to get data in my app from the web page. I do it like this:
I have a "Data" model I have gotten from jsonschema2pojo. In my activity I fill that "Data" object but when it comes the point of sending that information I don´t know exactly what to do.
I have my ApiService like this:

```
@POST("api/data/configuration")
 Call<Data> postConfigurationData(@Body Data datos);
```

And in my activity I send the "Data" object like this:

```
Call<Data> dataCall=service.postConfigurationData(datosNuevos);
```

"datosNuevos" is my "Data" object by the way.

Do I have to create the same route: "api/data/configuration" in my controller in my laravel webPage? In that case, would it be a get request?
Thank you.

EDIT

```
Route::post("data/configuration",[ConfigurationController::class,'getDataConfiguration'])->name('configurations.getDataConfiguration');
```

Comment: Since you are using POST, so you have to create a POST request.

Comment: Thank you very much @TicherhazFreePalestine . I have updated my post with the route. Do you mean that? And by the way, do you know how to get the information in my 'getDataConfiguration' function? Because I have no clue how it can be. And thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Is it working now? I feel like good to go

Comment: No, I´m sorry, @TicherhazFreePalestine. I don´t know why but when I do the post, I don´t get a successful response